# How do I run a Rake task every time a file is saved in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rake

How do I run a rake script automatically every time I save a file in Visual Studio? I can create a batch file that wraps the command. And I'd like to trigger it on `CTRL + S`. But, Visual Studio 2012 doesn't have macros.

[JP Boodhoo](http://www.developwithpassion.com/) has done it in many of his screen casts, but hasn't shared the implementation.

---

FYI, my `rakefile` looks like this

```
require 'albacore'

desc 'Build Solution'
msbuild :Build do |msb| 
  msb.properties :configuration => :Release 
  msb.targets :Clean, :Build 
  msb.solution = 'ProjoBot.sln' 
end 

desc 'Run Unit Tests' 
mspec :Test do |mspec| 
  mspec.command = 'Lib/Tools/MSpec/mspec-clr4.exe' 
  mspec.assemblies 'Src/Tests/ProjoBot.UnitSpecifications/bin/Release/ProjoBot.UnitSpecifications.dll'
end 

task :default => [:Build, :Test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the External Tools to run a batch file that executes the default Rake task.

```
@ECHO OFF
rake
```

I assigned the shortcut key `CTRL + S` to the tool, so that, when I save, the rake task is triggered! I hope this helps someone looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Does this implementation still execute the built-in save? Or have you lost that ability? It would be nice to see the batch file contents.

Comment: Anthony, my bat file is just a single liner all it contains is 

Rake


All I am doing is calling the default rake task.

Comment: my rake file is as follows

-----

require 'albacore'

desc "Build Solution"
msbuild :Build do |msb|
 msb.properties :configuration => :Release
 msb.targets :Clean, :Build
 msb.solution = "ProjoBot.sln"
end


desc "Run Unit Tests"
mspec  :Test do |mspec|
 mspec.command = "Lib/Tools/MSpec/mspec-clr4.exe"
 mspec.assemblies "Src/Tests/ProjoBot.UnitSpecifications/bin/Release/ProjoBot.UnitSpecifications.dll"
end

task :default => [:Build, :Test]

And yes Ctrl + S still works fine, the good thing is that if there is no batch file in a solution nothing will break and there will be no errors.

Comment: Cool, so you're depending on Ruby/Rake installed system-wide, so it's in your PATH. And you can call it from any command line. That's a good way to get started! I'm surprised that `CTRL + S` can be reassigned to your External Tool *and* still save the files. I didn't know VS could do that. I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some options that integrate with the command line that are ignorant of Visual Studio.

### The Ruby/Guard Way

I was playing with the [Guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard#readme) last night. You basically install guard and the [Guard rake plugin](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake#readme).

```
gem install guard
gem install guard-rake
```

You can create a Guard "template", a `Guardfile` with a plain Rake task in it

```
guard init rake
```

You can edit it to watch `.cs` files in the `source` directory, for example. (and

```
guard 'rake', :task => 'default', :run_on_start => false do
  watch(%r{^source/.+\.cs$})
end
```

Then start Guard

```
guard
```

You may need to use `-i` to turn off this "interactive" mode, which may generate errors on Windows!

```
guard -i
```

Guard runs like a little local server, showing logs

```
12:07:08 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
12:07:08 - INFO - Starting guard-rake default
12:07:08 - INFO - Guard is now watching at 'D:/temp'
[1] guard(main)>
```

And if you force a file change (I'm going to `touch` a fake file I set up in my test directory), you'll get the output of your rake task!

```
12:07:08 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
12:07:08 - INFO - Starting guard-rake default
12:07:08 - INFO - Guard is now watching at 'D:/temp'
12:07:54 - INFO - running default
building!...
[1] guard(main)>
```

### The PowerShell Way

There's nothing fancy out there that wraps up filesystem polling triggered actions, but that doesn't mean you can't build your own! I wrote a `.\guard.ps1` file that sits in my solution root. It has a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx) and waits for changes in a loop.

```
$here = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$here\source"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

while($true) {
  # timeout here lets the console process kill commands and such
  $result = $watcher.WaitForChanged('All', 3000)

  if($result.TimedOut) {
    continue
  }

  # this is where you'd put your rake command
  Write-Host "$($result.ChangeType):: $($result.Name)"

  # and a delay here is good for the CPU :)
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
```

You can see it working and printing when you `touch` or create (`New-Item <name> -Type File`) files. But, we can also execute rake very simply

```
rake
```

PowerShell will just go ahead and execute that as a native command. You could get fancy and make this script look and feel more like Guard (ok, not a lot more, but a little!)

```
param(
  [string] $path = (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition),
  [string] $task = 'default'
)

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $path
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

while($true) {
  $result = $watcher.WaitForChanged('All', 3000)

  if($result.TimedOut) {
    continue
  }

  rake $task

  Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
```

And you'd execute it like this

```
.\guard.ps1 -Path "$pwd\source" -Task 'build'
```

Comment: Wow Anthony!
Thanks for sharing your implementations. I guess your solutions are more geekier than mine :) certainly more professional but I went for a simpler solution which works great for me. The best thing is that because my external command looks for a batch file in solution directory, if it does not find it nothing breaks.
I like your implementation also, I will give it a try when I am messing with powershell. Thanks :)

Comment: You asked a good question. I think I'm going to try this for my solution. If you like it, please upvote!